# Why does the fill attribute of the SVG path element fill the entire bounding box in some Chrome conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, opentype, pathelement

I'm developing a SVG editing application with react. All text in SVG is converted into path elements in opentype.js.

At some point, the entire bounding box for some of the path elements is suddenly blacked out.
After investigating the problem, I found out that this happens under certain conditions.

- Display SVG in chrome.
- Set the path element's fill attribute to a monotone color (e.g., black, grey)
- Splitting the path element into smaller pieces seems to be correct

Is there any way to get the path element to display correctly in Chrome?

---

My Chrome version is 85.0.4183.121

I created CSB: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-cloud-q4ivo?file=/src/App.js

--- update ---

It's the actual screenshot.
Path element filled in black is here.

And I found the solution written in Answer.

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="144"
      height="72"
    >
      <path
        fill="black"
        d="M10.76 35.47L4.99 35.47Q6.40 24.08 18.04 24.08L18.04 24.08Q29.74 24.08 29.74 36.63L29.74 36.63L29.74 53.82Q29.74 55.86 31.61 55.86L31.61 55.86Q32.24 55.86 33.33 55.62L33.33 55.62L33.33 60.68Q31.89 61.03 29.88 61.03L29.88 61.03Q25.14 61.03 24.50 55.72L24.50 55.72Q19.62 61.03 13.78 61.03L13.78 61.03Q9.95 61.03 7.49 59.03L7.49 59.03Q4.25 56.43 4.25 51.33L4.25 51.33Q4.25 39.48 24.57 38.07L24.57 38.07L24.57 36.63Q24.57 28.90 18.04 28.90L18.04 28.90Q11.29 28.90 10.76 35.47L10.76 35.47ZM24.57 47.36L24.57 42.61Q9.53 43.35 9.53 51.05L9.53 51.05Q9.53 56.21 14.63 56.21L14.63 56.21Q18.11 56.21 21.41 53.54L21.41 53.54Q24.57 51.05 24.57 47.36L24.57 47.36ZM41.34 59.70L41.34 9.28L46.69 9.28L46.69 29.36Q51.08 24.12 56.18 24.12L56.18 24.12Q61.49 24.12 64.83 28.72L64.83 28.72Q68.34 33.64 68.34 42.26L68.34 42.26Q68.34 48.30 66.48 52.91L66.48 52.91Q63.14 61.14 56.04 61.14L56.04 61.14Q50.17 61.14 46.62 55.23L46.62 55.23L45.25 59.70L41.34 59.70ZM54.88 29.21L54.88 29.21Q50.77 29.21 48.41 33.40L48.41 33.40Q46.48 36.84 46.48 42.26L46.48 42.26Q46.48 48.13 48.55 51.86L48.55 51.86Q50.91 56.04 54.95 56.04L54.95 56.04Q58.50 56.04 60.57 52.42L60.57 52.42Q62.72 48.76 62.72 42.26L62.72 42.26Q62.72 35.89 60.26 32.38L60.26 32.38Q58.22 29.21 54.88 29.21ZM97.84 48.23L103.68 48.23Q100.86 61.14 90.07 61.14L90.07 61.14Q83.57 61.14 79.77 55.72L79.77 55.72Q76.32 50.77 76.32 42.61L76.32 42.61Q76.32 34.84 79.56 29.88L79.56 29.88Q83.36 24.12 90 24.12L90 24.12Q100.30 24.12 103.11 35.79L103.11 35.79L97.35 35.79Q95.84 29.14 90.07 29.14L90.07 29.14Q86.41 29.14 84.27 32.52L84.27 32.52Q81.95 36.14 81.95 42.61L81.95 42.61Q81.95 47.95 83.53 51.36L83.53 51.36Q85.68 56.11 90.07 56.11L90.07 56.11Q96.47 56.11 97.84 48.23L97.84 48.23ZM133.31 29.36L133.31 9.28L138.66 9.28L138.66 59.70L134.75 59.70L133.38 55.23Q129.73 61.14 123.82 61.14L123.82 61.14Q118.37 61.14 115.03 55.86L115.03 55.86Q111.66 50.73 111.66 42.19L111.66 42.19Q111.66 35.19 114.19 30.38L114.19 30.38Q117.53 24.12 123.75 24.12L123.75 24.12Q128.92 24.12 133.31 29.36L133.31 29.36ZM125.05 29.21L125.05 29.21Q121.32 29.21 119.14 33.26L119.14 33.26Q117.28 36.91 117.28 42.26L117.28 42.26Q117.28 48.06 119.00 51.64L119.00 51.64Q121.04 56.04 125.05 56.04L125.05 56.04Q128.67 56.04 131.06 52.42L131.06 52.42Q133.52 48.80 133.52 42.26L133.52 42.26Q133.52 36.95 131.66 33.54L131.66 33.54Q129.38 29.21 125.05 29.21Z"
      />
    </svg>
```

[image]

Comment: If you've found a Chrome bug, report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Will do.I'm sorry but would you tell me the link for bug report?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Nothing wrong on my Version 85.0.4183.121

Comment: As per [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), only add a link to a runnable code example _in addition_ to showing that [mcve] in your post, so that your question still makes sense once your external link inevitably becomes a 404. Also note that part of the MCVE work here is to figure our whether this is because of React, or not: what you're showing doesn't rely on React, so your MCVE should probably just be in plain HTML and JS.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I'll be careful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a chrome bug, but something to do with HW acceleration. Once I disabled HW acceleration and then enabled it, the bug went away.

Here is the report to Chrome bugtracker.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1135089